# How do I adjust the semmni kernel parameter in Fedora 13?

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora-13

I've done the usual edit of /etc/sysctl.conf to include the parameter, but it just tosses errors.  I haven't had to tune a kernel in a very long time, what's different about it nowadays (or have I simply forgotten how)?

edit:

Added "kernel.semmni = 2048" to the tail of /etc/sysctl.conf and then ran "sysctl -p".  End result is an unknown key error (apparently kernel.semmni isn't the valid name anymore?).

Comment: OK, this doesn't work under Oracle Enterprise Linux either.  There's *got* to be a way to change the number of system wide semaphores available, the default 128 is ridiculously low.  Any more ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.  Desipite what everything I found on Google suggested, semaphores aren't individually settable, they're all bundled together under "kernel.sem".  Added:

```
kernel.sem=250 32000 100 2048
```

to my /etc/sysctl.conf and I'm in business!

Answer (score 2):

You can see the list of valid sysctl params with `sysctl -a`.  I'd run that, see if it's changed in your newer kernel

Comment: Helpful, I was completely overlooking that option.  "semmni" is not a valid option on this kernel.  Rather unfortunate, since the software I'm trying to install says that I need to bump it from 128 up to 2048...  Argh.